# AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'edit', при написании бота discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Пишу бота на python с модулем discord.py, он должен каждые пять минут редактировать своё сообщение, меняя контент на полученный из файла. Вот сам код.

```
import discord, asyncio
from discord import utils

import config

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as {0}!'.format(self.user))

        while 1 > 0:
            f = open('TempList.txt', 'r')
            channel = self.get_channel(int(config.CHANNEL))
            message = channel.fetch_message(int(config.MESSAGE))
            message.edit(content = f)
            f.close()
            asyncio.sleep(300)

client = MyClient()
client.run(config.TOKEN)
```

При его выполнении я получаю следующую ошибку: AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'edit'. Не могу понять почему так, ведь в документации, для редактирования сообщения предназначена именно эта функция.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрите документацию к библитотеке. Если медод асинхронный - отмечают его словами async или coroutine в документации. Такие методы нужно вызывать или через [`await`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html) или через [`ensure_future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.ensure_future), [`create_task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task).

```
message = await channel.fetch_message...
await message.edit(content = f)
...
await asyncio.sleep(300)
```

Comment: Получаю следующее: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Message.edit' was never awaited
  message.edit(content = f)

Comment: тогда этот вызов тоже аваитнуть.